# How can i get list of all videos in swift

Tags: swift

I want to get the list of all videos which are stored in iPhone internally. I want to show all the video files in my application.

Comment: What do you mean by recorded and iPod ?

Comment: And I believe what you need to use is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit

Comment: I can't found this :( Please help me more :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a small example I created for you. You should know basics of table view to work with this.

**First - Add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist**

This helps you get permission from the user to access the photos library

[image: Info.plist for getting Photos app permission in iOS swift]

**Working with Photos App**

Here is some code that fetches videos from the Photos app on your device, loads it in a table view and plays it when the user taps on a specific video.

I have added comments in the code to help you understand

```
// Import Photos to work with Photos app
// Import AVKit to play videos
import UIKit
import Photos
import AVKit

class PhotosExperimentViewController: UITableViewController
{
    // Array to hold videos
    var videos: [PHAsset] = []
    
    // Create cell identifier for UITableView
    let tableViewCellIdentifier = "cell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Video Example"
        
        // Register a default UITableView Cell
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: tableViewCellIdentifier)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // Request access to PhotosApp
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { [weak self] status in
            
            // Handle restricted or denied state
            if status == .restricted || status == .denied
            {
                print("Status: Restricted or Denied")
            }
            
            // Handle limited state
            if status == .limited
            {
                self?.fetchVideos()
                print("Status: Limited")
            }
            
            // Handle authorized state
            if status == .authorized
            {
                self?.fetchVideos()
                print("Status: Full access")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchVideos()
    {
        // Fetch all video assets from the Photos Library as fetch results
        let fetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video, options: nil)
        
        // Loop through all fetched results
        fetchResults.enumerateObjects({ [weak self] (object, count, stop) in
            
            // Add video object to our video array
            self?.videos.append(object)
        })
        
        // Reload the table view on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return videos.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellIdentifier)!
        
        // Get video asset at current index
        let videoAsset = videos[indexPath.row]
        
        // Display video creation date
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Video from \(videoAsset.creationDate ?? Date())"
        
        // Load video thumbnail
        PHCachingImageManager.default().requestImage(for: videoAsset,
                                                     targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100),
                                                     contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                                     options: nil) { (photo, _) in
            
            cell.imageView?.image = photo
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Get video asset at current index
        let videoAsset = videos[indexPath.row]
        
        // Fetch the video asset
        PHCachingImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: videoAsset, options: nil) { [weak self] (video, _, _) in
            if let video = video
            {
                // Launch video player in the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.playVideo(video)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Function to play video player in AVPlayerViewController
    private func playVideo(_ video: AVAsset)
    {
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: video)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        
        present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code will give you these results

First permissions, I select allow access to all photos:

[image: Photos App Permissions]

Load all videos in your table view

[image: Retrieve or get or load videos and photos from Photos App in UITableView]

Tapping on any cell plays the video in `AVPlayerViewController`

[image: Play video PHAsset from Photos Library in AVPlayerViewController]

Here is an example of the full experience

[image: PhotoKit get Videos from iOS device using swift and display it in a UITableView and play it in an AVPlayerViewController]

Now you have everything you need to explore further. [I recommend reading the documentation properly.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit)